# cargo run throwing openssl error and doesn't compile

Tags: rust, openssl

```
  Compiling openssl-sys v0.9.61
error: failed to run custom build command for `openssl-sys v0.9.61`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\mooyb_000\Desktop\Projects\hello-rocket\target\debug\build\openssl-sys-845818f977db5f26\build-script-main` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  cargo:rustc-cfg=const_fn
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  X86_64_PC_WINDOWS_MSVC_OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset
  cargo:rerun-if-env-changed=OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR
  OPENSSL_NO_VENDOR unset

  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: Os { code: 5, kind: PermissionDenied, message: "Access is denied." }', C:\Users\mooyb_000\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\openssl-src-111.15.0+1.1.1k\src\lib.rs:123:44
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

getting this error when trying to do

```
cargo run
```

I tried installing this package through vcpkg but it was of no help does someone have the solution

Comment: As can be seen in [the relevant source code](https://github.com/alexcrichton/openssl-src-rs/blob/9cc3301e6168237d2b466cb92d5535e0a6252c51/src/lib.rs#L123), this is caused by the openssl build trying and failing to remove a stale build directory. Perhaps you tried to run `cargo` as administrator, and now your normal user can't touch some part of the `target` directory? Try deleting the `target` directory of your project and try again.

Comment: Same issue tried that

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar issue, running from terminal in Ubuntu.
For me the issue was that rustup was not installed in the correct way. (I had followed terminal instructions and ran something like `sudo apt get rust`).

For me, following https://rustup.rs/ installer solved the issues. It prompted me to remove existing Rust first, which you can do with either
`sudo apt remove rustup` or  `sudo snap remove rustup`.

(And yes, for most people the latter is completely redundant information, but if you like me are a complete beginner, and unlike me have no friend with linux skills to help, here it is. )